# Manually configure scrollbar's Y-Size

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

let me introduce what I want to do.

I'm creating a simple Tkinter program which uses a Treeview widget to display information for the user.

I was using .grid() at first, but I feel more comfortable using .place() now. The problem here is the scrollbar. [It doesn't fill the Y-Dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNFV7.jpg) like it does with .pack().

Instead, [I want to have this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm5ta.jpg)

As a bonus, [this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCtB8.jpg) when I use .pack()

This is the code, if you need it:

```
self.ah = Treeview(self.M, selectmode='browse')
self.ah["columns"] = ("id", "time", "pr")
#
self.ah.heading('#0', text='Description', anchor='c')
self.ah.column('#0', anchor='c', width=170)
#
self.ah.heading('id', text='ID', anchor='c')
self.ah.column('id', anchor='c', width=30)
#
self.ah.heading('time', text='time', anchor='c')
self.ah.column('time', anchor='c', width=100)
#
self.ah.heading('pr', text='stuff', anchor='c')
self.ah.column('pr', anchor='c', width=70)
#
self.ah.place(x=400, y=70)
#
self.ah.scroll = Scrollbar(self.M, orient='vertical', command=self.ah.yview)
#
self.ah.scroll.place(x=770, y=70)
self.ah.config(yscrollcommand=self.ah.scroll.set)
```

Thank you!
Also, any suggerence is appreciated. :)

Comment: Could you please create a [mcve] for your problem? This will make it much more likely that you'll receive quality help.

Comment: I'll have that in mind for future questions, thanks! and sorry for the inconvenients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pack the Treeview and the Scrollbar into a Frame, and then use place to position the Frame where you want it. Like this:

```
self.ah_frame = Frame(self.M)
self.ah = Treeview(self.ah_frame, selectmode='browse')
self.ah.pack(side=LEFT)
self.ah.scroll = Scrollbar(self.ah_frame, orient='vertical', command=self.ah.yview)
self.ah.scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y, expand=True)

self.ah_frame.place(x=400, y=70) # place the Frame that contains both the Treeview and Scrollbar
```

Also, I highly recommend you avoid `place` if at all possible. Widgets change size with different user settings, fonts, and OSes. Using place means your code looks the way you want it to on your computer, but not on others.

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly! The program I'm making will be used only in this computer, but I'll avoid `place` in the future.